# How to split out series in Pandas and apply it to a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split out series in a column and map it against a unique value (in this case user).

So far I have been able to get the data frame to look like this.

```
df1:
   user      weight
0  james     [100.0]
1  brandon   [60.0, 40.0]
2  brandon   [60.0, 40.0]
3  chris     [100.0]
4  james     [80.0, 5.0, 15.0]      
5  james     [80.0, 5.0, 15.0]
6  james.    [80.0, 5.0, 15.0]
```

I tried the [split explode method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows), but it creates duplicate rows.

What is the best way to loop through the series and update the data frame as this desired output:

```
df2:
0 james    [100.0]
1 brandon  [60.0]
2 brandon  [40.0]
3 chris    [100.0]
4 james    [80.0]
5 james    [5.0]
6 james    [15.0]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the `weight` column to contain lists with a single entry (`[100.0]`) or numerical values (`100.0`)?

Comment: `weight` is a list or string looks like list?

Comment: They are all weights that add up to `100`. If there is only one value, it would be 100. But in this example, all `james` values equal 100. So yes, I think they should be numerical values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop_duplicates` and `explode`

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates('user').explode('weight')
      user weight
0    james  100.0
1  brandon   60.0
1  brandon   40.0
3    chris  100.0
6   james.   80.0
6   james.    5.0
6   james.   15.0
```